# After Libgpuarray update "Segmentation fault" on matplotlib.pyplot import

Tags: matplotlib, theano

I am using a network version of AnacondaPython (that I am not controlling, therefore cannot install or uninstall anything) on several servers (CentOS).

Last week there was an update of Theano/Libgpuarray and now on one of the servers matplotlib.pyplot does not work properly anymore. When I go into python (2.7) and enter import matplotlib.pyplot I receive

"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

and python is smashed. This only happens on one of the servers and I am not sure what is the connection of this command and Theano. Also I am not sure what is special about this server besides that it has a slightly older set of CPUs than the other ones.
For pkg-config libgpuarray --version I receive 
0.27.1.

Anybody any idea what is messed up?

Comment: Since the problem occurred following an update out of your control, and the  problem only occurs on one computer in the network, perhaps you should contact the network administrators?

Comment: I did but he does not know what to do either. If I find out what causes the error I can contact him again.